# Padding Bytes observed when Reading IStream then writing FileStream

Tags: c#, istream

I've used the guidance here: https://github.com/geersch/WPD/blob/master/src/part-3/README.md to create a working c# implementation that copies data from my (Canon Camera) portable device using the COM interop.

I've observed that when 'PictureA' is copied using Windows Explorer it results in a file size of 5,999,261 bytes and a file size on disk of 6,000,640 bytes.

However when I use the c# implementation the file created is 6,000,640 bytes in size and has a file size on disk of 6,000,640 bytes (The same).

6,000,640 is the lowest multiple of 4,096 (target disk disk allocation sizing (bytes per cluster)) above 5,999,261.

So if I take the resulting file from Windows Explorer (Copy Paste Operation) and diff that against the file created by the c# implementation they are different at the byte level.

It appears that when I use the c# implementation it pads the number of bytes till it reaches the lowest multiple of the disk allocation size.

I want to understand why this behaviour is observed between the two copy methods. I want to copy byte for byte the original file.

Here is the method being used:

```
        public void DownloadFile(PortableDeviceFile file, string saveToPath)
    {
        IPortableDeviceContent content;
        this._device.Content(out content);

        IPortableDeviceResources resources;
        content.Transfer(out resources);

        PortableDeviceApiLib.IStream wpdStream;
        uint optimalTransferSize = 0;

        var property = new _tagpropertykey();
        property.fmtid = new Guid(0xE81E79BE, 0x34F0, 0x41BF, 0xB5, 0x3F,
                                  0xF1, 0xA0, 0x6A, 0xE8, 0x78, 0x42);
        property.pid = 0;

        resources.GetStream(file.Id, ref property, 0, ref optimalTransferSize,
                            out wpdStream);

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream sourceStream =
            (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream)wpdStream;

        //var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.Id);
        var filename = file.Name;

        FileStream targetStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(saveToPath, filename),
            FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

        unsafe
        {
            var buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            do
            {
                sourceStream.Read(buffer, 1024, new IntPtr(&bytesRead));
                targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, 1024);
            } while (bytesRead > 0);

            targetStream.Close();
        }
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sourceStream);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wpdStream);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you write `bytesRead` bytes instead of 1024? i.e. `targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);`?

Comment: `Read` is allowed to return bytes smaller that the number of bytes requested

Comment: You're always writing 1024 bytes at a time, even if the last read likely reads less. Thus, the final write will write those X bytes + whatever was left in the buffer from previous reads/write cycles. As @YacoubMassad notes, you shouldn't blindly write 1024 bytes every iteration.